# Sending an argument to a prototype function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, prototype

I am trying to understand how to use a prototype with an array of objects in JavaScript.  I am trying to send an argument to each Person object by using a subscript because I was thinking of using a loop with an index.  With the current code I keep getting an error message that needsGlasses is not a function.

```
//class constructor
function Person (name, age, eyecolor) {
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
this.eyecolor = eyecolor;
}

//array of Person objects
var peopleArray = 
[
new Person ("Abel", 16, blue),
new Person ("Barry", 17, brown),
new Person "Caine", 18, green),
];

//prototype
Person.prototype.needsGlasses=function(boolAnswer){
    if (boolAnswer ==1){
        console.log("Needs glasses.");
       }
    if (boolAnswer !=1){
        console.log("Does not need glasses.");
       }
 }

//when I try to send a '1' or '0' to an object in the array, I get an error.
peopleArray[0].needsGlasses(1);
```

Comment: As soon as I fix the syntax errors in `peopleArray`, this code runs just fine and returns the expected results.

Comment: @Kai — No need to do that

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Your code throws different errors to the one you claim.

Comment: if (boolAnswer ==1) {}
if (boolAnswer !=1) {}
:)

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors. To get your code working it may be defined as follows:

```
function Person (name, age, eyecolor) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.eyecolor = eyecolor;
}
Person.prototype.needsGlasses= function(boolAnswer){
    if (boolAnswer ==1){
        console.log("Needs glasses.");
    } else { 
        console.log("Does not need glasses.");
    }
}

var peopleArray = 
[
  new Person ("Abel", 16, "#00f"),
  new Person ("Barry", 17, "#A52A2A"),
  new Person ("Caine", 18, "#f00"),
];

peopleArray[0].needsGlasses(1);
```

Furthermore, you have unnecessary `if` statements.

You can try to play with this code on [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/tapipoq/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

It works but you code was full of sytax errors.

```js
function Person (name, age, eyecolor) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.eyecolor = eyecolor;
}

//array of Person objects
var peopleArray = 
[
  new Person ("Abel", 16, 'blue'),
  new Person ("Barry", 17, 'brown'),
  new Person ("Caine", 18, 'green')
];

//prototype
Person.prototype.needsGlasses = function (boolAnswer) {
  if (boolAnswer ==1) {
    console.log("Needs glasses.");
  } else {
    console.log("Does not need glasses.");
  }
}

//when I try to send a '1' or '0' to an object in the array, I get an error.
peopleArray[0].needsGlasses(1);
```